# Assigning values to a numpy array using indices and sub indices

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

This has bitten me a few times, and I can't tell if it's a bug or a feature.

```
nums = np.arange(10)
indx1 = np.array([2,4,6,8])
indx2 = np.array([0,3])
```

It looks like I can index `nums` either way

```
nums[indx1][indx2], nums[indx1[indx2]]
```

outputs `(array([2, 8]), array([2, 8]))`

If I want to re-assign those values, This doesn't work

```
nums[indx1][indx2] = 20
nums
```

outputting `array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])`

But this works as expected:

```
nums[indx1[indx2]] = 20
nums
```

outputting `array([ 0,  1, 20,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 20,  9])`

Why do I have to nest my index arrays rather than daisy-chain them?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think.

Even though above two methods return the same results, they are different when you do assignment operations.

---

`nums[indx1][indx2]` can be divided into two parts `temp = nums[indx]` and `temp[indx2]`.

step 1. `temp = nums[indx1]` slicing will create a **new** array return `[2 4 6 8]`

step 2. `temp[indx2]` will return `[2,8]`

so if you try  `nums[indx1][indx2] = 20`, it is equivalent to

```
temp = nums[indx1]
print(temp)
temp[indx2] = 20
print(temp)
```

This will not affect the original array `nums`.`array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])`

---

Why does the second method work?

`indx1[indx2]` return `[2, 8]`

`nums[[2,8]] = 20` will give you `array([ 0,  1, 20,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7, 20,  9])`. It works because you assign value to the original array `nums`.

Overall, the first one cannot access to the memory of `nums` but the second does.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable explanation. But then shouldn't it throw an exception if you try to assign a value to a temporary variable? I can't think of a situation where you would want a line of code that does nothing.

Comment: @I.P.Freeley it's not that simple. For example, if `indx1` is a slice or an integer it does not nothing but works as expected. The parser can't easily detect this because Python is so dynamic that from the code it cannot in general know the types of `nums` or `indx1/2`. And at runtime its very difficult to detect either because the temporary object doesn't know it's temporary.

Comment: Ah, that explains why I thought I had been able to do this in the past--I must have been chaining slices and indices rather than 2 sets of indices.

Comment: `numpy` doesn't alter the Python syntax or evaluation order.  `alist[1][2]` and `arr[idx1][idx2]` are evaluated in the same way.  The difference is in the `__getitem__` (or `__setitem__`) methods of the list and array classes.